# Create a fragment in fragment at childFragmentManager

Tags: android, fragment, fragmentmanager

I have a few questions.

I am using fragment in fragment frame. 
And I want to create a inner fragment in the child fragment of a parent fragment. Is this method efficient?  For A fragment in fragment, I use `childFragmentManager()`. And I add a fragment in child fragment using `childFragmentManager()`.

I don't know whether my method is efficient or not. 
If you have a good idea to solve this situation, help me plz...

Comment: It totally depends on how your fragments are related to each other logically. If fragment A is composed of fragment B & C, then use `getChildFragmentManager()`, if instead your activity is composed of A, B & C (where their UIs can overlap), then use `getFragmentManager()`.

Comment: How about is that child fragment in child fragment?

Comment: It's the same, just treat them as object. The only thing u need to differentiate is whether the parent is activity or fragment. Also take note that too deep composition may result in very deep layout hierarchy.